# ppi for Windows 7 phone and tablets

Tags: windows-phone-7, dpi, ppi

I am fairly new at windows 7 graphics creation. My understanding is that all Windows phone 7 and Windows tablet graphics should be created at 96 ppi, not 72 like iPhone and android. Is this correct?

The sample graphics from windows and also another icon pack seem to support this idea as does this article (even though it's older):

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/expression/archive/2007/10/31/trick-or-treat-resolution-96-ppi.aspx

Before moving forward, I just want to make sure I don't have any wrong ideas about Windows phone/tablet graphics.

Thanks in advance for any responses!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sticking to 96dpi shouldn't give you any problems on Windows or Windows Phone 7.

While not a wrong idea about graphics you do potentially have a wrong idea about Windows Phone (7) being comparable to a tablet:

Widnows Phone 7.0 (& 7.1) OS(es) are not and will never be tablet operating systems. All existing Windows based devices which are advertised as "tablets" either run a version of Windows (XP, Vista or 7) or are based on Windows CE.
If you try and create images which you can use across all of them without modification you are likely to run into issues.